# Subclass of UIView not drawing subviews working in storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiimageview

I have a subclass of `UIView` which contains another instance of `UIView`... in this case a `UIImageView`.

I really like using interface builder because it allows me to set the constraints of my views and keep them organized but when I add a view to the storyboard and change its class to be my subclass all I see  when I run my program is a white square.

I'm not really doing anything complicated with it. so far it only contains the one `UIImageView` instance. I can also tell that its being initialized correctly and being added as a subview because I've debugged it and looked through all the in-scope pointers.

Finally... If i initialize it and display it in code it works perfectly, but if I can I'd like to be able to set it up in the storyboard so that I can manage the constraints more easily.

Any Ideas as to why this might be happening?

Comment: Are you sure the `IBOutlet` is set?

Comment: What init methods do you have and what do they do?

Comment: Do you have an image in your image view? If not, then you should only see a white square.

Comment: Yes... through more debugger work I've discovered that the storage pointer for my UIImageView is set to nil which shouldn't happen. but I can't figure out why its happening. The image is in the bundle and its name and targets are set correctly. It works when I initialize it elsewhere in the code so I don't think its the image itself.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, it sounds like you have code in `initWithFrame`. If this is so, it will work when you create the object programmatically, but not when you use Interface Builder. This is because Interface Builder never calls `initWithFrame`.

If this is the problem, simply use `awakeFromNib` instead. If you want to be able to use with either IB or programmatically, create an instance method that does your initialization work and call it from both `awakeFromNib` and `initWithFrame`.